# How to convert complex Makefile to SConstruct

Tags: makefile, scons

I've got a somewhat complex Makefile I want to convert over to SConstruct so I can understand better how SCons works and apply it to a bigger project. I'm reading through the SConstruct User Manual https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/index.html the problem is its taking a long time to read through this (I'm only part way through chapter 7 and I've been reading in my breaks for a few days now). I'm mostly having trouble with specific advance stuff I can't understand how to do in SCons.

Here is my Makefile

```
TARGET = kmgTest
BINS = $(TARGET).bin 1st_read.bin
SCRAMBLED = 1st_read.bin
KOS_ROMDISK_DIR = romdisk
OBJS = $(TARGET).o $(KOS_ROMDISK_DIR).o
LIBS = -lkmg -lkosutils
CFLAGS = $(KOS_CFLAGS)

all: $(TARGET).cdi

clean:
    -rm -f $(TARGET).cdi $(TARGET).iso $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin 1st_read.bin $(OBJS) romdisk.* romdisk/*.kmg

$(SCRAMBLED): $(TARGET).elf
    sh-elf-objcopy -R .stack -O binary $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).bin
    $(KOS_BASE)/utils/scramble/scramble $(TARGET).bin $(SCRAMBLED)

$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJS)
    kos-cc -o $(TARGET).elf $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(TARGET).cdi: $(SCRAMBLED)
    mkisofs -G $(KOS_BASE)/../IP.BIN -C 0,11702 -J -l -r -o $(TARGET).iso .
    cdi4dc $(TARGET).iso $(TARGET).cdi

romdisk.o: romdisk.img
    $(KOS_BASE)/utils/bin2o/bin2o romdisk.img romdisk romdisk.o

romdisk.img: $(patsubst assets/RGB565/%.png,romdisk/%.kmg,$(wildcard assets/RGB565/*.png)) $(patsubst assets/ARGB4444/%.png,romdisk/%.kmg,$(wildcard assets/ARGB4444/*.png))
    $(KOS_GENROMFS) -f romdisk.img -d romdisk -v

romdisk/%.kmg: assets/RGB565/%.png
    $(KOS_BASE)/utils/vqenc/vqenc -v -t -q -k $<
    mv assets/RGB565/$*.kmg romdisk/

romdisk/%.kmg: assets/ARGB4444/%.png
    $(KOS_BASE)/utils/vqenc/vqenc -v -t -q -k -a $<
    mv assets/ARGB4444/$*.kmg romdisk/

%.o: %.c
    kos-cc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This is how far I've got with SCons

```py
import os

KOS_BASE = os.environ.get('KOS_BASE')

TARGET = Dir('.').path.rsplit('/', 1)[1] + "Test"       #Executable name (First part gets the name of the parent dir)
BINS = TARGET + ".bin" + " 1st_read.bin"                #Binaries
SCRAMBLED = "1st_read.bin"                              #Scrambled-file-name
KOS_ROMDISK_DIR = "romdisk"
OBJS = TARGET + ".o" + " " + KOS_ROMDISK_DIR + ".o"     #Objects
LIBS = "-lkmg -lkosutils"                               #Libs used when making the .elf file

CFILES = ' '.join(map(str, Glob('*.c')))        #Convert from list to string

CFLAGS = os.environ.get('KOS_CFLAGS')
env_dreamcast = Environment()
env_dreamcast['ENV']['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH']   #Import my PATH variable

env_dreamcast.Replace(CFLAGS=CFLAGS)    #Set the value for the environment to use
env_dreamcast.Command("kmgTest.o", "kmgTest.c","kos-cc $CFLAGS -c $SOURCE -o $TARGET")  #Complains about 2nd arg
```

To summarise what this is supposed to do, I have my own C compiler called "kos-cc" for a different architecture and I'm trying to build an executable using it and a few other things later on. Variables like "KOS_BASE" are defined in a shell file that my terminal/shell's profile sources and kos-cc, cdi4dc and sh-elf-objcopy are found under paths in my profile's PATH variable.

Right now it should be able to make `kmgTest.o` (kmgTest.c is present). The content of the command, when entered on a normal terminal/shell and executed, does work, but for some reason I get a strange error "/opt/toolchains/dc/kos/utils/gnu_wrappers/kos-cc: 50: exec: -O2: not found". For reference `CFLAGS` is a long string of compiler flags starting with `-O2`. If CFLAGS was empty, then I get the same error, but with `-c`. My guess is it doesn't parse to exec properly, but I don't see why this wouldn't work. I tried Object() as well as seen below, but it has the same issue.

```py
env_dreamcast = Environment(CPPPATH = ['.'], CC = 'kos-cc', CCFLAGS = CFLAGS)
env_dreamcast['ENV']['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH']   #Import PATH for us. This fiexes the "Unable to find kos-cc" thing
env_dreamcast.Object("kmgTest.o", "kmgTest.c")
```

I learn best by talking with people, but I don't know anyone who used/knows SCons. I would prefer to post this on something like an SCons forum, but I can't find one. Apologies in advance if this isn't appropriate to ask here, I just don't know where else to ask.

Comment: There's a lot here that's minimally a lot more complicated than it has to be and maximally incorrect.. What's the path to your compiler? $KOS_BASE/bin ?  Does this behave more or less like a normal C compiler?  (is it a cross compiler based on gcc?)

Comment: The path to the compiler is `/opt/toolchains/dc/kos/utils/gnu_wrappers/kos-cc`, and this is a cross compiler. However I realised something which fixes the issue, I'll make an answer post for it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realise "kos-cc" isn't an executable, its a shell file without the extension. And now looking back at that error `"/opt/toolchains/dc/kos/utils/gnu_wrappers/kos-cc: 50: exec: -O2: not found` this suggests there was an error within the executable (Not SCons). This is line 50

`exec ${KOS_CC} ${KOS_CFLAGS} "$@"`

What happened was I didn't import all my profile environment variables into my SConstruct environment meaning "KOS_CC" and "KOS_CFLAGS" were unset and hence it was giving errors like "Can't find -o, -O2 or -c" because that was the first argument it sees here and it treated it like a command.

The solution was to just import all KOS profile variables into my SConstruct environment like so and now it runs the command correctly and compiles

```py
env_dreamcast['ENV'].update({k: v for k, v in os.environ.items() if k.startswith('KOS_')})
```

Comment: While this solves your error it doesn't really answer the request for guidance on how to convert a makefile to SCons. I'd suggest you bring that question to the SCons User's mailing list. https://pairlist4.pair.net/mailman/listinfo/scons-users